# How to separate view from controller without using interface builder

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, xib

I want to create UI elements programmatically without using xib files. All of the examples I have found (UICatalog, ...) are creating UI elements directly in the controller methods. What is the best practice to keep up with MVC patternn and separate views from controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, all you have to do is to create a separate view class that will take care of creating the UI elements. Then in the controller class you simply create an instance of the view class.

Answer (score 1):

zoul is correct in his answer. To aid you in doing this, these is a tool that will convert an XIB to the same Objective-C code it would take to create the view:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/iphone-dev-convert-xib-files-to-objective-c.ars